# Why I am getting OutOfMemory Exception in Android?

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I am working with Android `GridView`. I have around 60 .png images each of size > 100kb. I made an adapter and set that adapter to the `GridView`. I followed the tutorial from [Google android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html). When I ran the application in emulator, the application threw an error as follows:

```
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 4976652 byte allocation with 982448 free bytes and 959KB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:973)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2423)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:758)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:402)
        at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:741)
        at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:397)
```

I am setting the `ImageView` with image as:

```
imageView.setResources(R.drawable.imagename);
```

My emulator has >700MB free RAM size. I don't understand why I am getting above exception.

Also, what is standard way to set the images in Android?

**NOTE**: When I reduce the number of images to around 4-5, the app runs just fine.

Comment: you are confusing file size and image size.

Comment: Each app is allocated a memory depending on the device up to some  MB. The 700MB is the RAM for the entire device , which wont't be allocated to your app. Also the views are recycled in the listview . You need to use proper caching and bitmap reuse to avoid memory leak. Try to use some image library like picasso to avoid this overhead

Comment: Show your adapter code.

Comment: @r7v. Thank you for the suggestion of picasso. I will try that.

Comment: @tier777, my code is exactly same as that of link that I had provided above to Google documentation.

Comment: @njzk, Thank you. I just edited the question. I hope it clear now.